# Waiting for a lock to release with ManualResetEvent and Quartz

Tags: c#, locking

> ***Follow-up to:*** [Waiting for a lock to release with Thread.Sleep()?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/waiting-for-a-lock-to-release-with-thread-sleep)

I've found the time I tried to rewrite my `WaitForLock`-Method to utilize the [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) Scheduler which I've been using for some months now for other stuff. It got a little bit more complicated but at least it now misses the dreaded `Thread.Sleep()` completely, which is a big improvement for me.

Though, it might now be too complicated.

```
/// <summary>Waits for the lock to be released within the given timeout.</summary>
/// <param name="lockName">The name of the lock.</param>
/// <param name="timeout">The timeout in seconds.</param>
/// <returns>True if the Lock was released.</returns>
public bool WaitForLock(String lockName, Int32 timeout)
{
    // IsLocked(String) does query the database for the status
    if(!locker.IsLocked(lockName))
        return true;

    using(ManualResetEvent reset = new ManualResetEvent(False)
    {
        ScheduleLockWaiter(lockName, timeout, reset);
        reset.WaitOne(timeout * 1000);
        // WARNING: This overload is only available in: 4, 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP2, 2.0 SP2
        // I spend a half day trying to figure that out.
    }

    return !locker.IsLocked(lockName);
}

/// <summary>Create and schedule the job to wait for the lock.</summary>
/// <param name="lockName">The name of the lock.</param>
/// <param name="repeat">The times it shall repeat.</param>
/// <param name="reset">The ManualResetEvent to report on.</param>
private void ScheduleLockWaiter(String lockName, Int32 repeat, ManualResetEvent reset)
{
    // Utilizing Quartz.NET

    String name = "LockJob_" + lockName;
    Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeSecondlyTrigger("LockTrigger_" + lockName, 1, repeat - 1);

    JobDetail job = new JobDetail(name, _lockJobGroup, typeof(LockJob));
    job.JobDataMap.Add("Locker", _locker);
    job.JobDataMap.Add("Reset", reset);
    job.JobDataMap.Add("LockName", lockName);

    if(_scheduler.GetJobDetail(name, _lockJobGroup) != null)
        _scheduler.UnscheduleJob(name, _lockJobGroup);

    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}


// Further down the road, our Job-Class
public class LockJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        ILocker locker = (ILocker)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("Locker");
        ManualResetEvent reset = (ManualResetEvent)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("reset");
        String lockName = (String)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("LockName");

        if(!locker.IsLocked(lockName))
        {
            context.Scheduler.UndscheduleJob(context.Trigger.Name, context.Trigger.Group);
            reset.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure if I have improved something, or created a beast which will devour me someday. Your thoughts on this?

**Update:** Since I still have the comment from [Brian Reichle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1432/brian-reichle) in my ears, I've moved on to make the waiting and acquiring of the lock one atomic operation.

Also the scheduled job has changed to directly acquire the Lock. Yes, I know that it tries to lock it twice on success (I just realized that, but did not see a way to change that).

```
/// <summary>Tries to acquire the Lock within the given timeout.</summary>
/// <param name="lockName">The name of the lock.</param>
/// <param name="timeout">The timeout in seconds.</param>
/// <returns>True if the Lock could be acquired.</returns>
public bool WaitForLock(String lockName, Int32 timeout)
{
    // boolean ILocker.Lock(String lockName)
    // Returns true if it was able to engage the lock.
    if(locker.Lock(lockName))
        return true; // Easy way out

    using(ManualResetEvent reset = new ManualResetEvent(False)
    {
        ScheduleLockWaiter(lockName, timeout, reset);
        reset.WaitOne(timeout * 1000, false);
    }

    return locker.Lock(lockName);
}

// Further down the road, our Job-Class
public class LockJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        ILocker locker = (ILocker)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("Locker");
        ManualResetEvent reset = (ManualResetEvent)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("reset");
        String lockName = (String)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("LockName");

        if(locker.Lock(lockName))
        {
            context.Scheduler.UndscheduleJob(context.Trigger.Name, context.Trigger.Group);
            reset.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any benefits in using Quartz.Net vs polling it like you did in the first question. This is a far more complicated way of polling in 1s intervals. I am not sure how your `Locker` code looks like, but making `WaitForLock` a member of that class (`Locker`) would allow it to signal any blocked threads whenever a lock is released. This is probably what [Travis](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2657/5368) had in mind: the purpose of `ManualResetEvent` is to provide synchronization without polling. You should post your code for the `Locker.Lock` method, it would be easier.

Comment: What version of .NET are you working with? I am asking because 4 provides some new [thread primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718) which may be of use.

Answer (score 5):

I read your original question and this one and don't see how using ManualResetEvent/Quartz adds anything valuable. As far as I understand the whole point of sleeping is just to avoid polling the DB too frequently.

Here some pseudocode...

```
create table lock (name varchar(50) primary key)


bool tryLockNonBlocking(name_to_lock) {
    try {
        insert into lock (name) values (:name_to_lock)
        commit
        return true
    } catch(UniqueConstraintViolation) {
        return false
    }    
}

void releaseLock(name_to_release) {
    delete from lock where name = :name_to_release
    commit
}


final POLL_PERIOD = 100 // msecs

bool tryLockWithTimeout(name_to_lock, timeoutSeconds) {
    waitTimeMS = timeoutSeconds * 1000
    while(true) {
        boolean gotLock = tryLockNonBlocking()
        if(gotLock)
            return true
        waitTime -= POLL_PERIOD
        if(waitTime > 0) 
            Sleep(POLL_PERIOD)
        else
            return false
    }
}
```

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

NB. This is just a very rough draft ... you might want to add some lock owner and check it in